# Can I use both CakePHP and Prado together in one project?

Tags: php, cakephp, prado

I can guess that this might sound obvious for some people out there, but I would like to know whether a Framework which has no complex folder-structure can be used within CakePHP.

Comment: Thx, i think this is totally correct here, there must be always a way doing stuff, nomatter what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd want to mix two frameworks with separate rules together, you should look up CakePHP Vendors: http://book.cakephp.org/view/538/Loading-Vendor-Files

This allows you to load any framework / library / class etc you wish because Cake doesn't assume a thing about your vendors, allowing you to load them in how you need (with say... a custom component for example)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing so - you probably just need to put the Prado stuff (which I'm completely unfamiliar with, by the way) in the `/app/webroot` directory of your Cake site.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is No. But you could if you needed to but these two frameworks have two very different approaches.  I am not sure where they could meet. CakePHP couple more likely be used within Prado but not the other way around because all layers of Prado are so heavily dependent on each other. Such as a prodo component will most likely need a prado form.

I am not sure why you would use them together but if are not using prado yet I would sudgest using YII. It is made by the same guys because they knew the limitations in prado. But conceptially simular and could play better with other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You should pick one framework as main and then you can use parts of another framework.

E.g. you'll use Prado with all its structure and then you'll require some favorite parts of CakePHP framweork like

```
// cli install
composer require cakephp/orm // you can require full cakephp/cakephp if you need
```

```
// in controller (prado, cakephp, lavarel, symfony)
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
....
public functoin view() // 
{
    $PostsTable = TableRegistry::get('Posts');
    $PostsTable->find('customFinder'); // take advantage of great CakePHP ORM
}
```

I do this sometimes, using CakePHP as main and then using Symfony/Lavarel parts as vendor.
You can see even basic installation skeleton `cakephp/app` loads some symfony parts and other vendors..